# Log4J1.2.12 jars imported when log4j2 dependencies state 2.11.2

Tags: java, selenium, log4j2

In my Maven project, Log4j2 latest dependencies state version 2.11.2. However; 1.2.12 is being imported instead. The only logging dependencies stated in the POM.XML file are as follow:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

In the repository folder located within the .m2 folder, there exists a 'log4j' folder that has a folder with the title '1.2.12'. Inside the 1.2.12 folder the following items exist:

_remote.repositories
log4j-1.2.12
log4j-1.2.12.jar.sha1
log4j-1.2.12.pom
log4j-1.2.12.pom.sha1

My log4j2.xml configuration file is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>

<Configuration status="WARN">
<Properties>

  <Property name="basePath">./logs</Property>       

</Properties>

<Appenders>
<RollingFile name="File" filePattern="${basePath}/prints-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" fileName="${basePath}/prints.log">
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{  yyyy-MMMM-dd:  hh:mm a :ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
<SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500"/>


</RollingFile>
<Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{  yyyy-MMMM-dd:  hh:mm a :ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
</Console>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
<Root level="trace">
<AppenderRef ref="File"/>
</Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Log4j2.xml file is located under a package named resources which is situated under a source folder named src/main/java of the Maven project. I also get an occasional message (1 out of 5 times) stating that log4j2 configuration file can not be found. I have tried cleaning the project in addition to deleting the jars and re-including the dependencies but nothing seems to work.

Comment: log4j1.2 could be a transitive dependency, you should check your dependency hierarchy/tree

Answer (score 0):

***log4j2:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (....)*** comes when application is not able to locate log4j2.xml/properties file.

**/src/main/resources** is the standard placement for this.

You mentioned yours is under src/main/java, please keep it under /src/main/resources. If log4j2.properties/xml file is not found under /src/main/resources then use -

PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j2.properties/xml");

Comment: Thanks. But where would I use : "PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j2.properties/xml");" ( where should I include it? ). I am new to Selenium.

Comment: First please keep your log4j2 under src/main/resources. If still not able to read out then under your runner class, you can have @BeforeClass which would runs only one during test cases execution there you shall implement configurator